# Call async function within for loop within streambuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, for-loop, async-await, stream

i have a technical doubt. Can you please let me know how to await a function in for loop within streambuilder. Function depends on data from streambuilder

I have streambuilder whics has stream of firestore data. Once the snapshot has data then i run a for loop to make a list of data within snapshot. Now the problem im facing is that how will i call a async function within for loop within streambuilder. This async function fetches data from other collection in firestore and depnds on streambuilder data

```
class LeagueGroupByListModel {
  String? name;
  Map? listData;
  LeagueGroupByListModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.listData,
  });
}

class PublicScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PublicScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PublicScreen> createState() => _PublicScreenState();
}

class _PublicScreenState extends State<PublicScreen> {
  //late PublicListController _publicListController;
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final DBServicesFootball _dbServicesFootball = DBServicesFootball();

  SeasonModelYear _seasonModelYear = SeasonModelYear();
  List<Matches?> listofStatus = [];
  String? wholeLeagueStatus;
  var listofLeaguesAsRound = [];
  List<LeagueModelFootball>? lgModelFootball = [];
  List<dynamic> ftLeagues = [];
  Map? groupedItems;

  getDataFromSeasons(int roundNumber) async {
    //lgModelFootball = await _dbServicesFootball.fetchDatafromDBWithDocID("fs_leagues_collection")
    String round = "round_" + roundNumber.toString();

    _seasonModelYear = await _dbServicesFootball.fetchDataFromSeasons(round);
    if (_seasonModelYear == null || _seasonModelYear.matches == null)
      return null;
    var uniqueList = Set<String>();
    listofStatus = _seasonModelYear.matches!.where((element) {
      if (element.matchStatus != null) {
        return uniqueList.add(element.matchStatus!);
      } else
        return false;
    }).toList();

    if (listofStatus.length == 1) {
      wholeLeagueStatus = listofStatus[0]!.matchStatus;
      //listofLeaguesAsStatus = [{wholeLeagueStatus: }]
      print("Round number ${listofStatus.length}");
      print(wholeLeagueStatus);
      return wholeLeagueStatus;
    } else
      return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    // _publicListController = PublicListController();
    super.initState();
  }

  var leagueModelFootballLiveList = [];
  var leagueModelFootballFutureList = [];
  String? publicLeagueName;
  int? lifePerUSer;
  bool? leaguePvt;
  List<dynamic> publicLeagues = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorManager.primary,
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _db.collection("fs_leagues_collection").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print("It has data");
                  List<dynamic> data =
                      snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> da =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return da;
                  }).toList();

                  // for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  //   if (data[i].isLive == true) {
                  //     leagueModelFootballLiveList.add(data[i]);
                  //   } else {
                  //     leagueModelFootballFutureList.add(data[i]);
                  //   }
                  //   //lgModelFootball![i] = data[i];
                  //   // leaguePvt = data[i]["leaguePrivate"];
                  //   // lifePerUSer = data[i]["lifePerUser"];
                  //   // publicLeagueName = data[i]["name"];
                  //   print(data[i].isLive);
                  // }
                  if (data.length > 0) {
                    //for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //if (data[i]["leaguePrivate"] == true) {
                    var uniqueList = Set<String>();
                    publicLeagues = data.where((element) {
                      if (!element["leaguePrivate"])
                        return uniqueList.add(element["uuid"]);
                      else
                        return false;
                    }).toList();
                    //}
                    //}
                    print("Pvt ${publicLeagues.length}");
                  }
                  Map groupByListName(List items) {
                    return groupBy(items, (item) => item.name);
                  }

                  if (publicLeagues.length > 0) {
                    List<LeagueGroupByListModel> itemList = [];
                    for (int i = 0; i < publicLeagues.length; i++) {
                      //Call the below function it is async function
                      getDataFromSeasons(publicLeagues[i]["startRound"]);
                      print("Whole Lg status $wholeLeagueStatus");
                      itemList.add(LeagueGroupByListModel(
                          name: wholeLeagueStatus ?? "Nothing",
                          listData: publicLeagues[i]));
                    }
                    print("Ite ${itemList[0].name} ${itemList[0].listData}");
                    groupedItems = groupByListName(itemList);
                  }
                  return publicLeagues.length > 0
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: AppPadding.p12,
                              bottom: AppPadding.p8,
                              left: AppPadding.p8,
                              right: AppPadding.p8),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                //fit: FlexFit.loose,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: groupedItems!.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    String status =
                                        groupedItems!.keys.elementAt(index);
                                    print("Status $status");
                                    print("It ${groupedItems![status]}");
                                    List itemsInData = groupedItems![status];
                                    return Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          status,

                                          //AppStrings.leagueName,
                                          // widget.publicData["isLive"]
                                          //     ? AppStrings.leagueName
                                          //     : AppStrings.leagueFutureName,
                                          style: getSemiBoldStyle(
                                            color:
                                                ColorManager.leagueTextColor1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: AppSize.s4,
                                        ),
                                        Divider(
                                          thickness: AppSize.s1_5,
                                          color:
                                              ColorManager.leagueDividerColor,
                                        ),
                                        ListView.separated(
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                              int index) {
                                            print("Itms ${itemsInData[index]}");
                                            return PublicListWidget(
                                              publicData: itemsInData[index],
                                            );
                                          },
                                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            return Divider();
                                          },
                                          itemCount: itemsInData.length,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : Center(
                          child: Text(
                            AppStrings.noPubLicLeagueText,
                            style: getBoldStyle(
                                color: ColorManager.white,
                                fontSize: FontSize.s16),
                          ),
                        );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      AppStrings.noPubLicLeagueText,
                      style: getBoldStyle(
                          color: ColorManager.white, fontSize: FontSize.s16),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              default:
                return ErrorScreen();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll suggest you to create a new Stream with all prepared data. Then provide that stream to the `StreamBuilder`. Please check the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080132/6185804).